# How do you look at console.log output of the amazon lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, serverless

When you do a

```
console.log('Loading function');
```

in an amazon lambda function, where does that go?

My setup
api gateway
lambda function nodejs6.10
curl  https://n2tredacted.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/redactedFunc

Comment: If you are using Serverless Framework you can simply access them in commandline.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

AWS Lambda logs are written to [CloudWatch Logs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/WhatIsCloudWatchLogs.html). Here's [how to access them](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-functions-logs.html):

1. select your Lambda function in the AWS console
2. click the Monitoring tab
3. choose View logs in CloudWatch

If you prefer to retrieve CloudWatch Logs outside of the AWS Console, then there are numerous CLI options:

- awscli: [aws logs get-log-events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/get-log-events.html)
- github: [jorgebastida/awslogs](https://github.com/jorgebastida/awslogs)
- github: [TylerBrock/saw](https://github.com/TylerBrock/saw)
- serverless: [sls logs](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/cli-reference/logs/) (if using [serverless](https://serverless.com/))
- samcli: [sam logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-logs.html) (if using [SAM](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/sam/))

Answer (score 14):

There are 2 ways to access logs of your Lambda Function.

> **Method 1 (Using Serverless CLI):**

Navigate to the root of your project folder and enter this in your command line:

```
sls logs -f myFunctionName -t
```

**-f** is for specifying the function name and **-t** is live tailing the logs in the command line.

> **Method 2 (Using CloudWatch Logs):**

Go to CloudWatch in the region where your function was deployed and head to Logs. You will find the logs of your function there.

Answer (score 4):

In the console Cloudwatch > Logs
Or with awscli:

```
aws logs get-log-events  --log-group-name /aws/lambda/my_group_name_here --log-stream-name stream_name_here
```

Some special characters like $ need to be escaped with a preceding \

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing this with API Gateway, console.log won't print in Test of API test.
But don't be confused it works fine and print logs in cloud watch.

Just go to monitoring tab of your lambda you will find your logs.